# How to get token from woocommerce rest api

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to get token from wooCommerce rest api in mobile app, I am using jwt_auth plugin for login customer it create token for me but when I want to use Password_reset plugin for forgot password jwt does not allow because it want token. so How can I get token without login.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate token without user login then it will decrease security of your app.

I would suggest you to create some custom endpoints for password reset and whitelist them from jwt like this -

```
add_filter( 'jwt_auth_whitelist', function ( $endpoints ) {
    return array(
        '/wp-json/custom/v1/webhook/*',
        '/wp-json/custom/v1/otp/*',
        '/wp-json/custom/v1/account/check',
        '/wp-json/custom/v1/register',
    );
} );
```

Comment: can you explain more that what exactly this function do, because I work with flutter not with wordpress and I am new in wordpress

Comment: You can create custom endpoints for password reset using this tutorial - https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-custom-endpoints-for-the-wordpress-rest-api/. After this you need want this end point to be accessible without token. For this you need to whitelist this end point using the function share above. Basically the above function is a filter which overrides a data. In this case the whitelist endpoints array

Comment: Thanks for explanation and answer but still I have the same error but your answer help with other problem can you suggest a way for my problem

Comment: You can use this plugin for a password reset using API  - https://wordpress.org/plugins/bdvs-password-reset/. You don't need any token from woocommerce for a password reset. If the jwt auth plugin asks for a token, you can whitelist the route for the password reset plugin. Please let me know if you still need anything else.

Comment: I use that and add routes to withelist but still have the same error I mean jwt want me token again

Answer (score 1):

You need make custom route without any token for your change password  and forget password

for make forget password and change password you need

1. check email or username exits
2. if exits send a verify code to email for confirmation
3. after check the code is valid make new custom rest api for change password